# How do I mount a volume in docker so files aren't owned by root?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I have a directory on my linux computer (Ubuntu 23.10) called:

```
/home/steve/foobar/foo
```

The directory and all of the files in it are owned by user steve (uid 1000) and group steve (gid 1000).

I want to mount it inside docker as /host/foo

No matter what I try all of the files inside docker end up being owned by root with group root.  I want them to be owned by user steve and group steve.

Here is compose.yaml:

```
services:
  pyapp:
    hostname: pytest
    container_name: pytest1
    command: 'sleep infinity'
    volumes:
        - /home/steve/foobar/foo:/host/foo
    build:
      dockerfile: testapp.dockerfile
```

And here is my testapp.dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy

ARG UID=1000
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/home/steve" \
    --shell "/bin/bash" \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    steve

RUN mkdir -p /host/foo
RUN chown steve: /host
RUN chown steve: /host/foo

USER steve
VOLUME /host/foo
```

To build I do:

```
docker compose build
```

To run I do:

```
docker compose run
```

And to get a command line inside docker I do:

```
docker exec -it pytest1 /bin/bash
```

What exact changes do I have to do so that all of the files under /host/foo are owned by steve with a group of steve?

Thank you.

(If it matters I am also running docker desktop).

Comment: On what platform are you running Docker (Linux/MacOS/Windows)?

Comment: @larsks... I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 as my base operating system.  I'll update the question to include that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need add the following to your docker-compose

```
user: "1000:1000"
```

So in your case

```
services:
  pyapp:
    hostname: pytest
    container_name: pytest1
    command: 'sleep infinity'
    user: "1000:1000"
    volumes:
        - /home/steve/foobar/foo:/host/foo
    build:
      dockerfile: testapp.dockerfile
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and unfortunately it didn't work.  The files in /host/foo are still owned by root despite being owned by steve on the host filesystem.  Any other ideas?